# Angularjs JSON treeview, json format issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to implement a JSON treeview with this [plugin](https://axelzarate.wordpress.com/2014/08/04/angularjs-tree-view-control/)

My issue is this line :

```
$scope.structure = { folders: [
{ name: 'Folder 1', files: [{ name: 'File 1.jpg' }, { name: 'File 2.png' }], folders: [
    { name: 'Subfolder 1', files: [{ name: 'Subfile 1' }] },
    { name: 'Subfolder 2' },
    { name: 'Subfolder 3' }
]},
{ name: 'Folder 2' }
]};
```

In my case, I'm reading a file that returns me a JSON format

```
[
    {
        "item": {
            "title": "Kids"
        }, 
        "children": [
            {
                "item": {
                    "title": "HELLO"
                }, 
                "children": []
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I thought using `JSON.parse(myFileContent)` should have been enough for having the same data structure as in the  `$scope.structure` but the data isn't displaying, i'm not getting errors.

How can I parse my file content to make it work ?

Answer (score 0):

First, the structure should be an object, since the directive differentiates "folders" from "files". So, considering you already define child elements inside a `children` property, you could wrap your array (assuming it's called `content`) into an object like so:

```
$scope.structure = {
    "children": content
};
```

Then, you'll need to override the default values for the property names in which the directive will try to get the values.

```
$scope.structureOptions = {
    foldersProperty: "children",
    displayProperty: "item.title"
};
```

And last, you add the `tree-view-options` attribute to the HTML element.

```
<div tree-view="structure" tree-view-options="structureOptions"></div>
```